# Element with background-image not visible

Tags: html, css

I'm relatively new to web development in pure markup. I've tried many times to make the jump but I usually don't get past the early stages because I make a small mistake in the syntax and can never find out where it is. This is one such case.

I can't even get a div to show it's style defined in css in the head. If someone can just point out really quickly the div id `#bg_cityscape` is not appearing, your small effort would go a long way to helping free me.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
    .hero_container{width:960; display: inline-block;}
    #hero_intro{width:960;}
    #bg_cityscape{ width:50%; background-image: url(<!--filepathreoved//-->);}
    #white_bar{background-color: white; width: 30%;}
    #portrait{;}
    #signature{;}
    #whitebar_text{;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="hero_container">
        <div id="bg_cityscape">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

*EDIT* Solved!!!! Thanks guys! I'm not sure which of the suggestions did it, but it's now working! I'll update the post after I've figured out if it was defining a fixed height or any height at all on the background-image containing div; or the units of measurement on the containers in the CSS.

Comment: You need set height of the `#bg_cityscape`, I read that you need your image to be percentage. You can use your image inside an `<img>` tag? That could be a possible solution

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare a `height` for the `div` and add `position`:

```
#bg_cityscape {
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    position:absolute;
    background-image: url(https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png);
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zb4dcLy1/1)**

Comment: I need the image to be a percentage.

Comment: also, your solution doesn't work in my code. If i just change the width from 50% to 500px, for example, I am still left with a blank window.

Comment: Set the `height` to `auto` that will prevent the image from distorting. Example: `height: auto`

Comment: @CodeChaser ^ when I set it to auto, img doesn't show up

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a unit measurement for the `.hero_container` and `#hero_intro` divs' width properties.

```
.hero_container{width:960px; display: inline-block;}
#hero_intro{width:960px;}
```

Add a `height` value for `#bg_cityscape` as well (however large you need it to be).

```
#bg_cityscape{ width:50%; background-image: url(/*image url*/); height: 200px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. The "border" line is just for showing the region.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
    .hero_container{width:960; display: inline-block;}
    #hero_intro{width:960;}
    #bg_cityscape{

        border:1px solid #00ff00; /* Show the region */        
        width:50%; 
        background-image: url('http://dreebies.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/free-pattern-renaissance-sprin.png');}

    #white_bar{background-color: white; width: 30%;}
    #portrait{;}
    #signature{;}
    #whitebar_text{;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="hero_container">
        <div id="bg_cityscape">
            Test
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks, i can see the dimensions of the object, but I background-image:url(); is still not functional. at least I know now that the div is printing. good thinking

Comment: You are welcome! That is a bit weird, since with the code above I can see the background image from Safari and Firefox. May be you can just copy the code to a new text file using .html extension, then try again.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont have contents in `<div id="bg_cityscape"></div>` you need to specify a height.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvq730xt/)

Comment: added height, still nothing.

Comment: @AndÚ did you added the unit for the height as well? I noticed in your code you didnt specify the units(px?) for width